# PoSh stop working after the installation of SQL Server 2014

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, poshserver

I'am currently using PoSH server to host a small statistics application (just for amdin usage) on my server.

After the installation of SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, the PoSh server refused to start with the error:

> AVERTISSEMENT : Could not detect PoSH Server Module Path.
>   AVERTISSEMENT : Aborting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from the fact that the installation of server 2014 management studio add a new path to `$env:PSModulePath`

```
C:\Users\BLANCJP\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
```

But the initial code suppose that the PoSh server Module is the last installed :

```
...
  # Test Module Paths
  Foreach ($ModulePath in $ModulePaths)
  {
    $ModulePath = "$ModulePath\PoSHServer"
    $ModulePath = $ModulePath.Replace("\\","\")
    $PoSHModulePathTest = Test-Path $ModulePath
    if ($PoSHModulePathTest)
    {
      $PoSHModulePath = $ModulePath
    }
  }
}

if (!$PoSHModulePathTest)
{
  Write-Warning "Could not detect PoSH Server Module Path."
...
```

I just add the break instruction to have my PoSh working again

```
...
  # Test Module Paths
  Foreach ($ModulePath in $ModulePaths)
  {
    $ModulePath = "$ModulePath\PoSHServer"
    $ModulePath = $ModulePath.Replace("\\","\")
    $PoSHModulePathTest = Test-Path $ModulePath
    if ($PoSHModulePathTest)
    {
      $PoSHModulePath = $ModulePath
      break
    }
  }
}

if (!$PoSHModulePathTest)
{
  Write-Warning "Could not detect PoSH Server Module Path."
...
```